# Calling a variable inside an items list of a container.Viewport / ExtJS and Geoext

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, openlayers

I'm quite new inside JavaScript frameworks.
Recently, I've been working on a Man Machine Interface using Geoext, extJS and OpenLayers.
For the moment, I've a simple panel and I want it to display a map. 
My code is like this :

*(note that I'm not displaying there the OpenLayers code to make the map, but there is no point to do so)*

```
    var mappanel = Ext.create('GeoExt.panel.Map', {
        title: "AZE TILE - AZE",
        map: map,
        center: '12.3046875,51.48193359375',
        zoom: 6,
        stateful: true,
        stateId: 'mappanel',
    });
```

And then, I have my Viewport :

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout:'border',
        id: 'BorderLayout',
        defaults: {
            collapsible: true,
            split: true,
        },
        items: [
        [...]
            {
                region:'center',
                title:'Représentation',
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                activeTab: 0, 
                split: false,
                collapsible: false,
                animCollapse: false,
                margins: '5 0 5 0',
                items: [
                    {
                        title: 'Tableau',
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Carte',  <- WHERE I WANT TO DISPLAY THE MAP CONTAINED IN THE PREVIOUS VARIABLE mappanel
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Graphiques',
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
```

I don't know how to do this. I found an example in the Geoext2 website, but all they do is calling the variable like this :

```
items: [
        mappanel
       ]
```

It is working but then, I can't add some more options to the items (like title).
I guess it is a simple work to get done but I can't figure out, forgive my newbiness :-) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy answer by the way, I found it myself.

```
 items: [
                    {
                        title: 'Tableau',
                    },
                    mappanel,
                    {
                        title: 'Graphiques',
                    },
                ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the GeoExt panel, nothing to be serious.
You can try to put your mappanel into another container:

```
items:[{
    title: "AZE TILE - AZE",
    items:[{
        xtype: 'container',
        items: [mappanel]
    }]
}]
```

By the way your code:

```
items: [
       {
           mappanel
       },
```

if mappanel is already an object, you don't have to use the curly brackets.

Comment: Hey, thanks for fast answer. You're right about your second answer, I don't need the {}. I've already tried to put an items into an items but it seems like it's not allowed :(.

Comment: By the way, If i put {} to declare mappanel I got an syntax error, so I've edited my post !